# Angular router.navigate promise tslint

Tags: angular, navigation, router, tslint

I have a method where I send some data from a component to a service, login user, and if it's successful I use this to navigate to the home component:

```
signIn() {
  this.service
    .signIn(some data...)
    .subscribe(
      () => {
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
     },
     ...
```

and I'm getting this tslint warning:

```
Promises must be handled appropriately (no-floating-promises)tslint(1)
```

I'm using `this.router.navigate(...)` in other places and I always get the same warning.

I saw that one way of handling this is adding void. Is there any other way? Would transforming it into an Observable help me in any way? Thanks for your help.

Comment: what you have inside `signIn` method?

Comment: return this.httpClient
      .post<Token>(this.signInClientUrl, {
        'username': username,
        'password': password
      })
      .pipe(catchError(error => this.handleSignInError(error)));

Comment: Same error with nextJS